GCM software optimization - R table calculation
I have written the python implementation below based on this AES-GCM spec document and the paper referenced within.  The latter had some significant changes compared to its initial draft.
I know my code works as I've A) gone through the test cases at the end of the paper with aad and plain text in non-16 byte lengths and B) successfully decrypted my results with other libraries.  That tells me my implementation of alg1 from the paper and the code that calls it is correct.
I am now in the process of implementing alg2 and alg3 from the paper to speed things up, but can't get the result of alg2(x) to be the same as alg1(x, h)
Could someone please let me know where I may have gone wrong below?  I'm pretty confident about table M and alg3, but not table R or alg2.
I took inspiration from this question which suggests alg3 can be tweaked to generate R but feeding that either of '04' or '40' followed by 30 zeroes didn't work.
That leads me to believe that one or more of the following may be the case:

leveraging alg3 to generate R is not a valid approach
leveraging alg3 to generate R is a valid approach, but it is not being called with the correct parameters
the alg2 pseudo code is wrong

I raise the last as a possibility as it seems odd that A is being saved from X[15] instead of Z[15] to be used after the j for loop.   The pseudo code changed between the initial and second paper to reference Z instead of X within the j for loop, so I think that it should be a reference to Z instead.
I tried changing that aspect without success plus a few other other things but I'm stumped so any guidance on why my alg1Result != alg2Result when I set a breakpoint in xorAndMultiplyByH would be most appreciated.

import math
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


R = bytes.fromhex('e1' + '0' * 30)
P = bytes.fromhex('40' + '0' * 30)
ZEROES = bytes.fromhex('0' * 32)


class Encryptor:

    def __init__(self, k, iv):
        self.k = k
        self.iv = iv
        self.h = self.encryptBlock(ZEROES)
        self.tableM = Encryptor.algorithm3(self.h, P)
        self.tableR = Encryptor.algorithm3(R, P)

    def encryptBlock(self, block):
        cipher = AES.new(self.k, AES.MODE_ECB)
        return cipher.encrypt(block)

    @staticmethod
    def xor(x, y):
        return bytes(a ^ b for (a, b) in zip(x, y))

    @staticmethod
    def algorithm1(x, y):
        z = ZEROES
        v = x
        for i in range(128):
            m = 128 >> i % 8
            b = y[int(i / 8)]
            if m & b != 0:
                z = Encryptor.xor(z, v)
            if v[15] & 1 == 0:
                v = (int.from_bytes(v) >> 1).to_bytes(length=16)
            else:
                v = Encryptor.xor((int.from_bytes(v) >> 1).to_bytes(length=16), R)
        return z

    def algorithm2(self, x):

        x = bytearray(x)
        z = bytearray(ZEROES)
        for i in reversed(range(1, 16)):
            z = bytearray(Encryptor.xor(z, self.tableM[x[i]]))
            a = x[15]
            for j in reversed(range(1, 16)):
                z[j] = z[j - 1]
            z = bytearray(Encryptor.xor(z, self.tableR[a]))
        z = Encryptor.xor(z, self.tableM[x[0]])
        return z

    @staticmethod
    def algorithm3(a, b):
        t = {128: a}
        i = 64
        while i > 0:
            t[i] = Encryptor.algorithm1(t[i * 2], b)
            i = math.floor(i / 2)
        i = 2
        while i <= 128:
            # 1 to i − 1
            for j in range(1, i):
                t[i + j] = Encryptor.xor(t[i], t[j])
            i *= 2
        t[0] = ZEROES
        return t

    def xorAndMultiplyByH(self, x1, x2):

        x = Encryptor.xor(x1, x2 + bytes.fromhex('00' * (16 - len(x2))))
        alg1Result = Encryptor.algorithm1(x, self.h)
        alg2Result = self.algorithm2(x)
        return alg1Result

    @staticmethod
    def increment(block):
        incr = ((int.from_bytes(block[12:]) + 1) % (2 << 31)).to_bytes()
        return block[:12] + bytes.fromhex('00' * (4 - len(incr))) + incr

    def encrypt(self, p, a):

        y = self.iv + bytes.fromhex('00000001')
        ey0 = self.encryptBlock(y)

        # hash A blocks into x
        x = ZEROES
        for i in range(math.ceil(len(a) / 16)):
            x = self.xorAndMultiplyByH(x, a[16 * i:16 * i + 16])

        # generate C and hash its blocks into x
        c = b''
        for i in range(math.ceil(len(p) / 16)):
            y = self.increment(y)
            ey = self.encryptBlock(y)
            ci = bytes(e ^ p for (e, p) in zip(ey, p[16 * i:16 * i + 16]))
            x = self.xorAndMultiplyByH(x, ci)
            c += ci

        x = self.xorAndMultiplyByH(x, (len(a) * 8).to_bytes(length=8) + (len(c) * 8).to_bytes(length=8))

        return c, self.xor(x, ey0)

# paper test case 4
e1 = Encryptor(k=bytes.fromhex('feffe9928665731c6d6a8f9467308308'), iv=bytes.fromhex('cafebabefacedbaddecaf888'))

c, t = e1.encrypt(
    p=bytes.fromhex(
        'd9313225f88406e5a55909c5aff5269a86a7a9531534f7da2e4c303d8a318a721c3c0c95956809532fcf0e2449a6b525b16aedf5aa0de657ba637b39'),
    a=bytes.fromhex('feedfacedeadbeeffeedfacedeadbeefabaddad2')
)

```

